# Myrtille Remote Access Gateway API

Tags: reactjs, remote-desktop, rdp

just want to ask if there are anyone experienced implementing API on Myrtille? I'm using React and wanted to launch the Myrtille Remote Access along with the stored credentials in React. I can't figure out where to setup the API.

Myrtille was the requirement to be used on our project and the documentations are limited. Just wondering if there are anyone who successfully implemented an API for it. If not what is the best alternative for Remote Access Gateway? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.